# Select all checkboxes for updating data in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I'm trying to update some of data from datagridview by selecting the checkbox headers for the rows I want to update and then pressing the update button. Problem is that it's not updating the rows as intended, it updates all columns except one. I need a way to update all columns of the rows that have been selected by the checkbox header.

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        checkColumn.Name = "chk";
        checkColumn.HeaderText = "Select";
        checkColumn.Width = 50;
        checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
        checkColumn.FillWeight = 10;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
    }
```

```
    private void checkboxheader_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["chk"].Value) == false)
            {
                row.Cells["chk"].Value = true;
            }
            else
            {
                row.Cells["chk"].Value = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    private void btnCHKPO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Check Purchase Request ?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                int i = 0;
                    var addRows = new List<DataRow>();
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["chk"].Value) == true)
                        {
                            addRows.Add(((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row);
                            var ST = 2;
                            row.Cells["ISSU_FLG"].Value = ST;
                        }
                    }
                    if (addRows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if ((addRows != null))
                        {
                            for (; i < addRows.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    objConnect.UpdateDatabase(addRows.ToArray());
                                    Po = 1;
                                }
                                catch (Exception err)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(err.Message,
                                         "Information",
                                         MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                         MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk,
                                         MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                                }
                            }
                            if (Po == 1)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Purchase Request Has Been Checked !" + "\n" + "Please search the data again",
                                                  "Information",
                                                  MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                  MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk,
                                                  MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                                btnSave_Click(this, new EventArgs());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Row For Checking PO Info !",
                         "Error",
                         MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                         MessageBoxIcon.Stop,
                         MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What column is missing? Is it 'ISSU_FLG' by any chance?

Comment: ISSU_FLG just for updating data. Basically I want to update those column values in database on checkbox value change by selecting all checkboxes and click update button.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I don't know what your problem is, but I have a few ideas.

Firstly, there is the chance that for some reasons, when you're adding the rows, there are some missing. From the code you've given, I can't see anything wrong with the code, looks like you're correctly adding to the list based on the checkbox value. To ensure this isn't the problem, put a breakpoint on the if statement `if (addRows.Count > 0)` and check the value of the 'addRows' variable to ensure all the rows you expect are in there. If you're not sure on how to do this, google debugging in visual studio (or whatever IDE you're using).

Secondly, there is an issue with this `objConnect.UpdateDatabase(addRows.ToArray());` I don't recognise this code, and not sure what it does. Is this part of EFC? Are you using a custom library to update your database? This is likely where the problem lies. Based on the code you've provided, I'm unsure of the structure of the database, how it's updated, and what technologies your using to do so. Maybe provide the setup for the database in your question? But this looks like where the issue may arise.

I've also got some optional feedback, there is some issues with your code in general that I have so advice for you on, but lets work through it piece by piece.

Firstly, instead of:

```
private void checkboxheader_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["chk"].Value) == false)
        {
            row.Cells["chk"].Value = true;
        }
        else
        {
            row.Cells["chk"].Value = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Do this:

```
private void checkboxheader_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells["chk"].Value = !Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["chk"].Value) ;
    }
}
```

This improves the readability of your code, it's basically saying 'Set this cell's value to the opposite of what it was', without the need for the large if statement.

Then in the first foreach block, change:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["chk"].Value) == true)
```

to

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["chk"].Value))
```

Same principle. If statements will execute code based on a boolean.
E.g.

true == true is true.

false == true is false.

The point being, there is no need to compare your value to true, as when it's true, it'll be true regardless, and when it's false, it'll be false regardless.
Look into boolean algebra to learn more.

Combine the next two ifs.

```
if (addRows.Count > 0)
{
    if ((addRows != null))
    {
```

Like so:

```
if (addRows != null && addRows.Count > 0)
```

Note: always check for null in a variable before you use it, if you don't you risk a null reference exception. Does your program crash if you try to update with nothing selected?

Finally:

```
for (; i < addRows.Count(); i++)
{
    try
    {
        objConnect.UpdateDatabase(addRows.ToArray());
        Po = 1;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message,
             "Information",
             MessageBoxButtons.OK,
             MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk,
             MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
}
```

Currently, your adding to the rows you want to update to 'addRows', and here your iterating over each row. Now I think what you're trying to do is update each individual row, one at a time, but then you call

> objConnect.UpdateDatabase(addRows.ToArray())

This is passed an array, which is multiple rows. So your updating the full set or rows, rather than each individual row. So there is no need to loop through each row. To fix this code, change it to:

```
try
{
    objConnect.UpdateDatabase(addRows.ToArray());
    Po = 1;
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message,
         "Information",
         MessageBoxButtons.OK,
         MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk,
         MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
}
```

So remove the for loop.

You can do even more than this, but it's a decent start.

Comment: It still doesn't work. 
As additional information, if I check the box manually one-by-one, it will work. But if I select checkbox header it will leave one column

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. Which of your columns does it leave out? 'ITEM NAME'? 'QUANTITY'?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I meant not COLUMN but ROW

Comment: I've rewritten the answer, I don't know what the problem is, but looks like the database setup.

Comment: I'm sorry for being late to reply your comment, I've tried your code and implemented into my syntax but it doesn't work, it still leaving 1 row (1 line)